# Fatal error MapKit Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

hola estaba intentando cargar un mapa para mi aplicación de IOs con una ubicación determinada y el zoom adecuado estaba siguiendo un tutorial pero en mi casa se produce un error, adjunto la imagen del error que aparece ademas del codigo del mapa. en este caso estoy utilizando Xcode 7 y Swift 2.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        maptal()

    }

    func maptal()
    {
        let tallat:CLLocationDegrees = 27.175015
        let tallon:CLLocationDegrees = 78.042139

        let tajcordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tallat, longitude: tallon )

        let latdelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let longdelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let tajspan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latdelta, longitudeDelta: longdelta)

        let tajregion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: tajcordinate, span: tajspan)

        mapView.setRegion(tajregion, animated: true)

        let tajanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        tajanotation.title = "taj mahal"
        tajanotation.subtitle = "holita"
        tajanotation.coordinate = tajcordinate

        mapView.addAnnotation(tajanotation)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que el problema se encuentre en la conexión del `@IBOutlet` con el XIB/Storyboard correspondiente del mapa. Revísala.

Comment: revise y realice de nuevo las conecciones y nada

Comment: Pues es raro... en esa línea solo puede ocurrir que `mapView` sea `nil` ya que un `MKCoordinateRegion` nunca devuelve un `optional`. Asegurate y sino prueba de crear una instancia de `MKMapView` directamente en la clase para probarlo.